# How do i make one class be active at one time using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

Code:

```
var $anchors = $(".box_one, .box_two");

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var $elem = $(e.target);
    if ($elem.hasClass('box_one') || $elem.hasClass('box_one_active')) {
        $elem.toggleClass('box_one box_one_active');
        $anchors.not($elem).addClass('box_two').removeClass('box_two_active');
    }
    else if($elem.hasClass('box_two') || $elem.hasClass('box_two_active')) {
        $elem.toggleClass('box_two box_two_active');
        $anchors.not($elem).addClass('box_one').removeClass('box_one_active');
    }
    else {
        $('.box_one_active').addClass('box_one').removeClass('box_one_active');
        $('.box_two_active').addClass('box_two').removeClass('box_two_active');
    }
});
```

In the code above when box_one is clicked box_one_active takes box_one's place and when box_two is clicked box_two_active take's box_two's place.

How do I change the code so that when `box_one_active` is **active** that `box_two_active` is also **not active** at the same time.  Meaning, the user has to click one to disable the other and enable one.

How do I do that?

Comment: I would recommend *not* doing that. Instead, simply toggle an `active` class, and write the CSS to act on the combination of classes (e.g., `.box_one.active { /* ...styles... */}` and `.box_two.active { /* ...styles... */}` instead.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? i am new to this nto sure what you mean. thanks

Comment: Here's an existing one you can build on top of: http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/SE5N7/1/

Comment: @ starbucks: Sure, I've added an answer with examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not doing that. Instead, simply toggle an active class, and write the CSS to act on the combination of classes instead.

Here's an example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/erefad/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/erefad/1/edit)

CSS:

```
.box_one {
  /* Styles for `box_one` when not active */
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box_one.active {
  /* Adds/overrides further classes for when `box_one` is also `active` */
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.box_two {
  /* Styles for `box_two` when not active */
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box_two.active {
  /* Adds/overrides further classes for when `box_two` is also `active` */
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box_one">This is box_one</div>
<div class="box_two">This is box_two</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Note how just adding and removing the "active" class changes things.

In the above I'm not *overriding* styles, but you could: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/erefad/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/erefad/2/edit)

```
.box_one {
  /* Styles for `box_one` when not active */
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box_one.active {
  /* Adds/overrides further classes for when `box_one` is also `active` */
  background: red;
}
.box_two {
  /* Styles for `box_two` when not active */
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box_two.active {
  /* Adds/overrides further classes for when `box_two` is also `active` */
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I make the class go back to it's original one when clicked again? and how do i make the class go back to it's original when when clicked elsewhere (blank space etc)

Comment: @starbucks: Look at the example again: I already do that. This is the joy of *combining* classes. The code I've shown above will only allow one element to have the `active` class (by removing it from anything that has it, and then adding it just to the thing that was clicked). If you play with the example, it should be fairly clear how it works.

Comment: You are using $("div").click(function(), how can i specify only those two divs?

Comment: @starbucks: Using CSS selectors. See the jQuery (and CSS) documentation for details. (But what you show in your question would work, for instance.)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the active selector to remove all traces of the active class.

In your case, your active classes are changing, which kind of complicates things.

You could just make the active class `.box_active` which would simplify things significantly.

Then to remove it, do

```
$('.box_active').removeClass('box_active');
```

Comment: What I'm saying is you're over-complicating things.  You don't need a unique active class for each box.  You can simply use `.box_active` for ALL of the boxes, and style it using basic CSS selectors `.box_one.box_active`